# gulp autoprefixer compiling to .scss not .css

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, autoprefixer

I'm trying to use gulp autoprefixer, but when it compiles code it creates a .scss file in my public folder. 
My file structure is as follows:

Root > dev > sass > main.scss

&

public > css > main.css

When I make changes in main.scss the general sass code compiles fine, but when using autoprefix it creates a main.scss file in my public/css directory.

My gulpfile.js is as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./dev/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dev/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch('./dev/sass/**/*.scss',['styles', 'autoprefixer']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the sass compilation in the autoprefixer task.

it should be

```
gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dev/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});
```

Autoprefixer is made to work on plain css and does not compile sass. So you have to do it by yourself before passing the stream through autoprefixer.